# html prefix namespace collision

Tags: html

I currently have the following `html prefix namespaces`

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/
dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
og: http://ogp.me/ns# rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
schema: http://schema.org/ sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#
sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types# skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#
xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# ">
```

I was reading something and came across this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Here are my questions:

1./ Does adding this to my html web page **interfere/collide** with the current prefix namespace I have?

2./ For the situation when it says `if (gte IE 9)` why is there a closed comment `<!-->` before the html declaration and `<!--` after the declaration

3./ What can i do with this sort of declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can only have one `<html>` tag, but you could add the attributes from your first example to the `<html>` tag in the second. What are you trying to achieve?
2. Your second example contains *conditional comments*. They are only supported by older versions of Internet Explorer. Other browsers will treat them as normal HTML comments - i.e. they will ignore them. The last line of the example closes the comment before the HTML tag so that all non IE browsers will still see the `<html lang="en">` tag. If it was instead written as

   ```
   <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
   ```

   the `<html>` tag would be inside the comment and would therefore be ignored by all browsers.
3. The purpose of the code you posted is to output an IE-version specific class to the `<html>` tag. It would allow you to write CSS declarations for targetting specific IE versions, e.g.:

   ```
   body {
      background-color: white;
   }

   .ie7 body {
       background-color: red;
   }
   ```

   This would make the page background white for everyone except users of IE7, for whom it would be red.

In practice these sorts of solutions aren't used as commonly these days, unless you have a pressing need to support IE versions that Microsoft themselves no longer support.